# Detach/re-attach div depending on checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get 2 divs to toggle depending on a checkbox state but can't get it to work.

If the checkbox is checked, only div class "2" should be displayed. If the checkbox is not checked, only div 1 should be displayed.

I got half of it to work how I want, but can't figure out how to properly toggle the content. Another problem is that the toggled content does not re-appear where it was before.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum <span class="1">1</span><span class="2">2</span> dolor sit</p>
</div>
```

.

```
y = $('.2').detach();
var x;
$('#toggle').change(function() {
 if (!this.checked)
   x = $('.1').detach();
 else
   $('.content').append(x);
});
```

[See my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjea1vzj/)

Comment: NOTE: I can NOT use a "active" class or display:none solution

Comment: Logic isn't complicated...if you detach x it makes sense you want to put back y ...no?

Comment: Also the html shows those spans in `$('.content p')`

Comment: @AffiLead you want something like https://jsfiddle.net/dollarsview/sjea1vzj/1/ ?

Comment: let me know if this is in different to what you expect

Comment: THANK YOU Usman! You saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `show` and `hide` methods to toggle the content based on the condition of the checkbox being checked or not.

> Another problem is that the toggled content does not re-appear where
>   it was before.

The problem was that you were appending the content with the `append` method which appends it at the end of the element.

```js
$('.2').hide();

$('#toggle').change(function() {
  if (this.checked){
    $('.2').show();
    $('.1').hide();
    return
    }
  $('.2').hide();
  $('.1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum 
<span class="1">1</span>
<span class="2">2</span> 
dolor sit
</p>
</div>
```